# How do I know if the Linux server killed my process and which process it killed?

Tags: linux, process, kill, kill-process

It seems my server killed a process due to it using too much RAM. Is this possible? If it can happen, how can I know when and what process it killed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/726879/280393

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's quite possibly OOM killer, killed your process. You may be able to find out what when etc by looking in the logs.

```
egrep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages
```

The actual log file varies by distribution so it could also be `/var/log/syslog` or even

```
egrep -i -r 'killed process' /var/log
```

Comment: Not only OOM killer can kill your process.

Have a look at both dmesg and /var/log/messages. Also look at your application log to see if something went wrong before it was killed.

Avoid using grep to parse log files, you could miss a line like this one :

Jun 10 04:02:07 servername kernel: programname[3324]: segfault at 000000000000001a rip 00002af7f092dcd4 rsp 00007fff010ddf68 error 4

Comment: also, just because the oom killer kills a process, that does not mean that the process killed is the one causing trouble,.

Comment: @befreeandgood:grep is the perfect tool for the job when, like I was, you are looking for a articular piece of text. Why don't you provide your own answer then there's plenty of room in the database for them.